# Cannot pass parameter as a query string in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter i want to pass parameter as query string rather than segment i have seen other links but they didn't work. I want to use query string on this particular controller only. Below is the code that i am using:

```
<a  href="<?=base_url()?>sample_qp/new_view/?id=<?=$a2?>">
 <label class="fils-label">
Reload Page
  </label>
</a>
```

and in controller:

```
public function new_view($id)
{   $id=$this->input->get('id');
    $data['name']=$id;
    $this->load->view('load_new_sample_view',$data);
}
```

i have set

> $config['enable_query_strings'] = true; and $config['uri_protocol'] =
>   "PATH_INFO";   but the issue is i am getting 404 page not found error.

Comment: If you have not used Apache config or .htaccess did you forget to add index.php in the url?

Comment: @Arjun: i have removed index.php from url through .htaccess

Comment: Try to concatenate values: `<?php echo base_url() . 'sample_qp/new_view/?id=' . $a2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 01**

Pass like this

```
<a  href="<?=base_url()?>sample_qp/new_view/<?php echo $a2 ?>">
```

> **Make sure `short_url_tag` is on**

**In Controller**

```
public function new_view($id)
{
    if(empty($id))
    {
        echo "Invalid Token";
    }
    else{
        echo($id);
    }
}
```

---

**Method 02**

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php?c=sample_qp&m=new_view&id=<?=$a2?>">
```

**In application/config.php**

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
```

**In Controller**

```
$id = $this->input->get('id');
echo $id ;
```

Comment: when i am passing it as a segment like this http://projectname/controller/method/a/x/a/a/Javascript%20ios%20Adobe/0 i get following error Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security. I have searched a lot but can't find a solution for that.

Comment: you can use `$this->uri->segment(n)` . `n` means value

Comment: but Abdulla that is also causing error Not Acceptable when i click on that link it is working ok when it has only one word for eg Javascript in the 5th segment. What s the soln. for that. Please help to sort out my issue.

Comment: @user3653474 include `index.php`. Some time its hangs without it

Comment: update config.php
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Comment: @Abdulla : it is redirecting to following url Projectname/index.php?c=sample_qp&m=new_view&id=Ashish%20Amit%20Kumar and shows 404 page not found.

Comment: post your full url

Comment: it is on localhost http://localhost/myproject_server/index.php?c=sample_qp&m=new_view&id=Ashish%20Amit%20Kumar

Comment: It says this url is not found.